# Geocoder java gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to get user to enter a location address and use google maps in gwt to display the location on a map and use the location for other services.  I'm using gwt-map 3.8.  The javadoc online isn't very helpful in describing how this class works and I can't find any examples online.  anyone has any ideas?

This is what I have so far:

```
private void geocode()
{

    final String addr = addressBox.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
        addressBox.setFocus(true);

    addressBox.setText("");

    Geocoder G = Geocoder.create();
    GeocoderRequest GReq = GeocoderRequest.create();
    GReq.setAddress(addr);

        // should this be just create or createarray? it won't let me use createarray
    GeocoderResult GResult = GeocoderResult.create();


com.google.maps.gwt.client.Geocoder.Callback gcallback = new Geocoder.Callback() {      

        @Override
                // i don't understand this handle part, the first parameter is not 
                //defined in the javadoc.  I looked around online and it seems to be a 
                //array of geocoder result but I can't make the array because it's a 
                //javascript object
        public void handle(GeocoderResult a[], GeocoderStatus b) {

}}};
```

thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

**I believe what you are looking for is this:**

```
String address = address1 + "," + number + "," + address2 + "," + city;
        GeocoderRequest request = GeocoderRequest.create();
        request.setAddress(address);
        Geocoder geoCoder = Geocoder.create();
        geoCoder.geocode(request, new Geocoder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void handle(JsArray<GeocoderResult> a, GeocoderStatus b) {
                if (b == GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    GeocoderResult result = a.shift();
                    map.setCenter(result.getGeometry().getLocation());
                } else {
                    Window.alert("Aconteceu algo errado no google ao pegar este local, confira endereco");
                }
            }      
            });
```